# Issue in displaying GameObject programmatically Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a gameObject programmatically by creating a mesh using vertices and faces only. The GameObject is created but I can't see anything displayed. I have searched for the problem but haven't found any satisfying answer. I have another question i.e. i know that the vertices in faces should be in clockwise direction but what does that mean? for example suppose I have a face with vertex indices 5,6,7, then do I first access the vertices array and check where each vertex lies and arrange their indices in clockwise fashion in the faces array? Perhaps I am going wrong in this but I have tried arranging the vertex indices in 'Faces' array in every manner but it still is not working.

```
    // Vertices is a double array
    mesh.vertices = Vertices.ToArray();
    // Faces is an int array
    mesh.triangles = Faces.ToArray();

    mesh.RecalculateNormals();

    mesh.RecalculateBounds();

    mesh.name = "Imported Model";


    model = new GameObject("Model");

    MeshFilter meshFilter = model.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();

    meshFilter.mesh = mesh;

    model.AddComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"clockwise direction but what does that mean?"_ - it's used in the winding order of vertices that make up a face.  Faces are only visible from one side and the side is defined by the winding order associated with the 3D engine. If you get it wrong then it won't be visible from the side you expect. e.g. the ground may only be visible if you are beneath it

Comment: @MickyD I understand that. Unity uses clockwise direction faces according to my knowledge. But in order to determine the clockwise order of vertices, do i need to know where the vertices are located in 3D space or can i just suppose that ascending order of vertices is the clockwise direction?

Comment: No, because when determining the vertex indices that define a face, you are doing so from the point of view of a _single face_, which being by definition **flat** essentially reduces the problem to that of 2D.  When specifying the indices, imagine you are looking at the face from the direction of the face normal.  So if this were a cube, you would repeat this operation 6 times

Answer (score 0):

No one can see what your `Vertices` and `Faces` looks like so I wouldn't rule out a problem from there.

The only problem I see now is not adding a shader. If you don't add shader to the Mesh, it **will** be visible in the **Scene View** with a purple color but it will be **invisible** in the **Game View**.

The last line of your code:

```
model.AddComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer));
```

should be extended to:

```
MeshRenderer renderer = model.AddComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer)) as MeshRenderer;
renderer.material.shader = Shader.Find("Particles/Additive");
```

Your Mesh should now display. Otherwise, there is something wrong with your vertices,triangles which were not posted in your question. Understanding the clockwise stuff is hard without visual images. This [guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYMQ2ErFz0s) explains it the best on youtube with a real labeled box and I suggest you watch that before making any comment.